# Modifying the path inside an archive for extraction

Tags: unix, archiving, tar, extract

I would like to change the path of extraction of a `.tar.gz` archive. The files are supposed to extract as `./1/2/3/4/files`, `./1/2/3files` and so on.

The `.1/2` part of those is common to all the files.

My question is, how can I modify the extraction path to extract into `./2/` and completely ignore the `1` directory?

Comment: I assume Linux, but tagging the OS would probably be a good idea too.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you use the `--strip-components=n` option for this using [gnu tar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar).  It strips **n** leading directories from the paths.